# Store data in db with ajax in wordpress issues

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, wordpress

I've been dealing with this issue for two days now. I've been through all 500 internal server errors to the code alerting that something went wrong. I'm trying to store data in my db through ajax in a module that i've been editing for cubepoints.

here's my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: cp_transfer.ajax_url,

    type: "POST",

    dataType: 'json',

    data: {
        action:'cp_module_store_data',
        'sacrifice': sacrifice,
        'recipient': f.selectedUser,
        'points': f.cp_transferAmount,
        'message': f.cp_transferComment
    },
    error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        if(data.success==true){
            location.reload();
        } else{
            alert("something went wrong");

            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

and the function that is being called is as follows:

```
function cp_module_store_data() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sacrifice=isset($_POST['sacrifice']);
    $message = htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['message']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $recipient = $_POST['recipient'];
    $points = $_POST['points'];
    $status = "Pending";
    $from_stat = "Funded";
    $to_stat = "Pending";
    $invoice = rand(1000,100000);
    $user = get_user_by('id', $recipient);
    $wpdb->insert('wp_funds', array(
        'Status'=>$status,
        'fromUser'=>$user,
        'toUser'=>$recipient,
        'Amount'=>$points,
        'invoice'=>$invoice,
        'from_stat'=>$from_stat,
        'to_stat'=>$to_stat,
        'title'=>$message),
    array(
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s')
    );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_cp_module_store_data', 'cp_module_store_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cp_module_store_data', 'cp_module_store_data');
```

The following is failing to insert the code in the db however I don't know what happened but at some point i got 3 entries but with the wrong values and i only found out about them later on so i don't remember what i had done back then. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any errors in your Javascript console or PHP logs? As a code nit, making random invoice numbers is never a good idea. It is possible to have duplicate values, and your code doesn't seem to do anything to prevent this.

Comment: thanks for answering. There's no errors whatsoever in the console. I'll have to check the php logs and see if i have access to that i'm working on a private server. I'm aware of the random invoice i just have it like that for now until i fix the db issue that has been taking most of my time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WP, but there is probably some way of checking if the DB had some sort of error. May want to check that as well.

Comment: Thanks again for replying, I fixed the issue, there were some php errors from the module that i was editing prior to the function that i was calling and these errors were ruining everything. I was able to check the php error logs which was your suggestion in the first place and once again i would like to thank you for that :)